# How to show value in multiple field through AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to show multiple values on change of one form text field. I can do it for one field but I can't do it for multiple fields. If I echo multiple values through AJAX they are shown in a single fileld or each field I mentioned in `getElementById`.

I used this JavaScript:

```
function iteminfo(vid) {

    var strURL = "item_info.php?id1=" + vid;

    var req = getXMLHTTP();
    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('pro_info1').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                } else {
                    alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                }
            }
        }
        req.open("GET", strURL, true);
        req.send(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your existing code. The easiest way (to my way of thinking) is to have your server return some JSON, and then your JS can extract the individual values and set them in the corresponding fields.

Comment: What does the AJAX responseText look like? Have you considered using [JSON](http://www.json.org/) (or another data exchange format)?

Answer (score 0):

A vague answer for a vague question:

> *Code snippet removed*

**Update:**

It depends on the way your AJAX `responseText` is formatted. I will assume it contains different values for the different fields (e.g. `pro_info1`, `pro_info2`, etc.), and that each value should be used to update the corresponding field.

In such cases, it is advisable to use a data exchange format. [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is a common choice for most AJAX communication. Format `item_info.php`'s response like this:

```json
{ 'pro_info1': 'Value 1', 'pro_info2': 'Value 2' }
```

Then update your JavaScript to parse and handle the response, like so:

```
// ...

if (req.status == 200) {
    var response = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
    for (var fieldName in response) {
        var field = document.getElementById(fieldName);
        if (field !== null) {
            field.innerHTML = response[fieldName];
        }
    }
} else {

    // ...
```

Don't forget to load [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in the `<head>` of your page.